# Autoload, Registration error on Magento Community 2 installation using Docker on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: magento2, exception

I am attempting to get **Magento 2 Community** working in my local environment using **Docker** and am running into the same error when I finally get to check the admin screen. After I've finished installing, I cannot enter the `bin/magento` CLI without also seeing the error in the shell.

This is the error I see in the browser when I get to the admin screen and in the shell:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar' not found in
> /www/vendor/magento/framework/registration.php:9 Stack trace: #0 /www/vendor/composer
> /autoload_real.php(73): require() #1 /www/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(63):
> composerRequire6dfc6a905630f73646996ff0d5c91c2f('07ec02c7e667fdc...', '/www/vendor/com...') #2
> /www/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit6dfc6a905630f73646996ff0d5c91c2f::getLoader() #3
> /www/app/autoload.php(30): include('/www/vendor/aut...') #4 /www/app/bootstrap.php(33):
> require_once('/www/app/autolo...') #5 /www/pub/index.php(13): require('/www/app/bootst...') #6 {main}
> thrown in /www/vendor/magento/framework/registration.php on line 9

I've tried starting from square one several times and I think I'm simply missing something or do not understand the nature of this error. I've searched a lot online and I have not found an answer, but a couple others who have had the same problem and there is no answer. Is it a cache issue? Is it a certain module that I need to uninstall?

I would greatly appreciate any pointers or tips you might have for me to fix this problem. I've tried clear cache, dumpautoload, and re-initializing the database several times to no avail.. Losing my mind over here

Comment: try installing/updating composer

Comment: I think that is all handled with Docker. I ran ```docker-compose exec magento composer install``` just fine and admin sign on in the browser works without anything in the vendor directory.